# Probability of selecting bulbs such that the room is not lighted

Tags: probability

**Question:-** In a room there are three lamp holders and there are 12 bulbs of which five are defective.  If three bulbs are selected at random to be put into holders, then what is the probability that the room is not lighted ?

---

**Similar question :-** [Three bulbs are required to light a room. Out of 15 bulbs, 6 are defective. Probability that room will be lighted?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975255/three-bulbs-are-required-to-light-a-room-out-of-15-bulbs-6-are-defective-prob)

---

I wanted to understand why the following approach is incorrect ?

let me name the five defective bulbs as B1, B2, B3, B4, B5 and the three holders as H1, H2, H3

$\frac{1}{5}$ * $\frac{1}{4}$ * $\frac{1}{3} * 3! = \frac{1}{10}$

So for the first holder, let's say I choose B1 as the defective bulb out of the 5 defective bulbs, then for the 2nd holder I choose B2 and for the third holder I pick B4

Reason for 3! ->  Each bulb can go to any of three holders like in my example there could be a case in which B1 goes in the 2nd holder, B2 goes in the 1st and B3 goes in the 3rd and so on.

Comment: What probability is $\frac{1}{5}$ meant to represent?  Recall there are five defective bulbs out of 12, so why is this not instead something like $\frac{5}{12}$?

Comment: By $\frac{1}{5}$, I meant the probability of selecting one defective bulb out of the five defective ones for the first holder , why should it be $\frac{5}{12}$ ? As per my understanding this is representing the probability of choosing 5 defective bulbs out of a total of 12 bulbs

Comment: "*Why is the approach incorrect*"  Simply put, you are multiplying probabilities and numbers together which do not describe the situation you are interested in.  Your answer and analysis does not involve the number 12 and so is not utilizing all relevant information and so can be assumed to be incorrect, noting that we should expect our probability to increase if we were to increase the number of working bulbs.

Comment: We are already given that there are 5 defective bulbs out of 12, then why would my sample space not reduce to these 5 bulbs only ?

Comment: Because... presumably... our person hoping to light the room will not *intentionally seek out* the defective bulbs, and when selecting a bulb will select from the full amount of remaining bulbs at random, not just from the defective ones.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing the meaning of your numerator with the meaning of your denominator.  Your denominator can describe the sample space which should have been *all possible ways of putting three bulbs of any kind into lamps*, which if you insist can be $12\times 11\times 10$ if you always do it in the order lamp1, lamp2, lamp3... at which point your numerator would be the number of ways this can be done were we to only pick defective bulbs which would be $5\times 4\times 3$, giving an answer of $\dfrac{5\times 4\times 3}{12\times 11\times 10}$

Comment: Oh I think I am getting what you are trying to convey , by taking 5 defective bulbs in my sample space I am making it a certain outcome that he will always choose a defective bulb, so let me try again should it be $\frac{5}{12}$*$\frac{4}{11}$*$\frac{3}{10} * 3!$

Comment: The 3! is incorrect and unnecessary here.  If you insist on not only caring about which lamp gets which bulb, but also care about the order in which you fill the lamps, then the numerator can be $5\times 4\times 3\times 3!$ if you insist, but the denominator will also have a $3!$ as well and would have been $12\times 11\times 10\times 3!$.  Similarly, we could have ignored which lamp was which and gotten a final answer of $\dfrac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{12}{3}}$, which of course equals the rest.  If you make a decision on how to present the sample space you must be consistent for numerator too.

Comment: You can see that the $3!$ is incorrect here with your work by considering an extreme case where there were actually only the defective bulbs.  The answer wouldn't be $\dfrac{5}{5}\times \dfrac{4}{4}\times \dfrac{3}{3}\times 3!$ though since that would have equaled $6$ which is not a valid value for a probability to have, noting that probabilities are always between 0 and 1.

Comment: Understood, got your point ! , My initial thought behind doing 3! was to order the lamps into the holders, but now I see it is being taken care by $5*4*3$ itself.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am curious.  What is the source of the problem?  Also, are you currently taking a Probability/Combinatorics class?

Comment: Hey, I had this as a practice problem given by my faculty in the class.  Yes, I am taking classes to understand these topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability you have computed does not answer the question

> If three bulbs are selected at random to be put into sockets, what is the probability that all are defective?

but rather the question

> Given that the three chosen bulbs are defective, what is the probability that three *particular* defective bulbs (say, $B_1, B_3, B_5$) were chosen?

These questions are quite different. In the first, your sample space is all collections of $3$ bulbs from the $12$ total bulbs (there are thus $\binom{12}{3} = 220$ equally likely outcomes). The number of "successful" outcomes (those in which all bulbs are defective) is $\binom{5}{3} = 10$. The desired probability is then $\frac{10}{220} = \frac{1}{22}$.

(Note that here, I do not consider the ordering of the bulbs in the sockets, but you can solve the problem the same way even if you consider ordering - both numerator and denominator scale by the same factor.)

In the second question, your sample space is all collections of $3$ bulbs from the $5$ *defective* bulbs. The number of total outcomes is thus $\binom{5}{3} = 10$. The number of "successful" outcomes in this problem is $1$ (there is only one desired triple), giving the $\frac{1}{10}$ you calculated.